# cross-compiling using NDK, undefined references to le32toh and be32toh

Tags: android, c, linker, android-ndk

I am trying to build a shared library, ultimately cross-compiling a piece of code that uses references to *be32toh* and *le32toh*.  If I build this piece of code and create an executable out of it, I get no errors:

```
    include $(CLEAR_VARS) 
    LOCAL_SRC_FILES:= ubertooth.c ubertooth_helper.c 
    LOCAL_MODULE := ubertooth 
    LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += jni/libusb jni/libbtbb 
    LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := libc libusb libbtbb 
    LOCAL_LDLIBS := -L$(SYSROOT)/usr/lib -llog  
    include $(BUILD_EXECUTABLE)
```

Here it compiles successfully:

```
    Compile thumb  : ubertooth <= ubertooth.c
    Compile thumb  : ubertooth <= ubertooth_helper.c
    Executable     : ubertooth
    Install        : ubertooth => libs/armeabi/ubertooth
```

However, when I try to build it as a shared library by only changing a single line in the *Android.mk*:

```
    include $(CLEAR_VARS) 
    ...
    include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

I now get the following errors:

```
    Compile thumb  : ubertooth <= ubertooth.c
    Compile thumb  : ubertooth <= ubertooth_helper.c
    SharedLibrary  : libubertooth.so
    ./obj/local/armeabi/objs-debug/ubertooth/ubertooth.o: In function `stream_rx_file':
    ubertooth.c:224: undefined reference to `be32toh'
    ./obj/local/armeabi/objs-debug/ubertooth/ubertooth.o: In function `cb_lap':
    ubertooth.c:281: undefined reference to `le32toh'
    ./obj/local/armeabi/objs-debug/ubertooth/ubertooth.o: In function `cb_hop':
    ubertooth.c:417: undefined reference to `le32toh'
    ./obj/local/armeabi/objs-debug/ubertooth/ubertooth.o: In function `cb_btle':
    ubertooth.c:506: undefined reference to `le32toh'
    collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I don't understand why I would get this linking error when building a shared library, but not when building the executable.  And, if I want to build the shared library, how to properly link to something I'm missing?

[Here is ubertooth.c](http://ubertooth.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/ubertooth/trunk/host/bluetooth_rxtx/ubertooth.c?revision=560&view=markup)

Comment: What is the difference when building an executable and shared lib when you use "ndk-build V=1" to build? Are there any -D flags which are different?

Answer (score 3):

well, apparently these macros are named differently in the NDK found in sys/endian.h:

```
__uint64_t  htobe64(__uint64_t);
__uint32_t  htobe32(__uint32_t);
__uint16_t  htobe16(__uint16_t);
__uint64_t  betoh64(__uint64_t);
__uint32_t  betoh32(__uint32_t);
__uint16_t  betoh16(__uint16_t);

__uint64_t  htole64(__uint64_t);
__uint32_t  htole32(__uint32_t);
__uint16_t  htole16(__uint16_t);
__uint64_t  letoh64(__uint64_t);
__uint32_t  letoh32(__uint32_t);
__uint16_t  letoh16(__uint16_t);
```

So, I used *letoh32* and *betoh32*